# Flash - Chrome Linux vs Chrome Windows

Tags: firefox, video, google-chrome, flash, chromium

What is the difference between Flash in Chrome for Linux and Chrome for Windows?

I am asking because in Ubuntu 14.04, Chrome will not play certain Flash-based live video streams (specifically Sportsnet and TSN). I get the ads without issue, but the video stream just shows a black screen. I have tried the Pipelight solution for Firefox, but it is horrible. Nothing syncs, and it ends up freezing after 3 or 4 minutes, which requires FF to be restarted. Not good when trying to watch anything.

In Windows, both TSN and Sportsnet stream live flawlessly.

If there is some kind of DRM garbage required that Windows has natively, is there a way (other than Pipelight) to get either Chrome or Chromium to work for these live streams?

Thanks.

PS. Chrome in my Ubuntu install runs everything else without issue. It is only these two that show black screens.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Yes, it's DRM garbage. Pipelight is likely your only hope for native-like playback, otherwise a virtual machine just for your streaming sports.

Comment: I figured. There was an update for Pipelight libraries today, and it makes the video work a bit better, but still goes out of sync in about 5 minutes. Visually better though.